# Check if an memory address is within the current process's stack space

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, callstack, ptrace

I'm adding a feature to my debugger (I'm using Ptrace to manipulate the traced process as well as libbfd/libopcodes) to unwind the stack and determine if discrepancies exist between each CALL's allocated stack space and a statically derived local variable size, printing the address and local stack size of each frame along the way.

My general methodology is to take the address in the base pointer (`EBP`/`RBP`), increment the pointer to should should contain the stored frame pointer, dereference that address, examine it with `PTRACE_PEEKDATA` and repeat until I dereference an address occupying an area outside the stack.

I know how to check code/data segment registers, but ideally I'd like a method to check if I'm still inside the callstack even if the segmentation has been changed by W^X memory pages or an otherwise nonexecutable stack.

In short, how can I check (in the general case) when I've moved outside the stack without triggering a general protection fault?

(As as aside, I realize I'm operating on the assumption that checking an address's page segment is the ideal methodology here -- perhaps another simpler method exists to determine if an address is within the current process's stack space)

Comment: Yes, but in a perfect world there would be a portable solution that doesn't depend on any information from /proc.

Comment: The C standard doesn't offer any portable ways of accessing OS-specific or hardware-specific information or functionality (except, perhaps, for `system()`). If your C program depends on said info/functionality, it's doomed to be poorly portable. You may somewhat improve portability if you stick to POSIX functionality, but that improvement will only be an improvement for POSIX compliant OSes. For all others it will be the opposite of improvement.

Comment: So be it. Do any libraries abstract it out?

Comment: Off-hand, I don't know. See POSIX APIs and tools.

Comment: Do you mind turning this into an answer?

Comment: If you think it's helpful, I can turn this into an answer. I wasn't sure you wanted a portable solution as that doesn't seem to be indicated in the question.

Comment: The portability is a post hoc requirement, a solution for linux is absolutely sufficient here.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard doesn't offer any portable ways of accessing OS-specific or hardware-specific information or functionality (except, perhaps, for system()). If your C program depends on said info/functionality, it's doomed to be poorly portable.

You may somewhat improve portability if you stick to POSIX functionality, but that improvement will only be an improvement for POSIX compliant OSes. For all others it will be the opposite of improvement. Likewise, there may be something that's always available on Linux (specific functions or tools or libraries) that you may use. Off-hand I can't point you to such. You need to do further research or wait for other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the code of the [pstack](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pstack1.html) command which is printing the content of the stack of a running process. This code is getting the base address from a `link_map` structure and store it inside the field `l_addr`. This field is set inside the function `readLinkMap()`:

```
static void readLinkMap(int pid, ElfN_Addr base, struct link_map *lm, 
                        char *name, unsigned int namelen)
{
  /* base address */
  lm->l_addr = (ElfN_Addr) ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid,
                                  base + offsetof(struct link_map,l_addr), 0);
  /* next element of link map chain */
  if (-1 != (long) lm->l_addr || !errno)
    lm->l_next = (struct link_map *) ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid,
                                            base + offsetof(struct link_map, l_next), 0);
  if ((-1 == (long) lm->l_addr || -1 == (long) lm->l_next) && errno) {
    perror("ptrace");
    quit("can't read target.");
  }

  loadString(pid, base + offsetof(struct link_map, l_name), name, namelen);
}
```